# Automatically monitor installations on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server

Is there a program -- free or commercial -- that can monitor *and* log software installations **automatically**, on Windows Server 2003/2008/2012?

The Application team seems to have a habit of doing changes without proper documentation, including installation of things.

And we can't *yet* remove them from the Administrators group; long story. So we SysAdmin had to have a way to log changes on those servers, to be able to pin the blame, so to speak.